# How can I get the NUnit Retry iteration programmatically?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

In NUnit 3 you are able to decorate your tests with the `Retry` attribute to run through a test x number of times if it returns a failure. Is there a way to programmatically retrieve how many times the test has been retried?

I would like to execute some code depending upon how many iterations the current test has gone through, such as:

```
if(CurrentTest.Retries > 1)
{
   //do something
}
```

I have checked under `TestContext.CurrentContext`, but there appears to be no way of accessing the attribute values nor how many times the current test has run through via the `Retry` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that. NUnit maintains the count internally.

Your workaround would be to maintain an instance member that tracks the count, initializing it to zero and incrementing it with each execution of the method. If you wanted to do this for more than one method, each would need its own counter.

It seems to me that this would be a reasonable feature request to make of the NUnit team.

Answer (score 5):

You might wanna try

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.CurrentRepeatCount
```

This works with NUnit 3.0